# App Maker- Issues while trying to retrieve a list of all users in my department

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm working on some little app using Google App Maker and I want to load the users who are in the same department as me on the application start up.

I created a datasource named "Person" which goes to the directory, then I created another one called "DepartmentMembers" and inside that I put a script to query the directory based on the email of the active user in the session and find his department name. Then using another query I wanted to list the users based on that department name.

However I'm getting the following error when previewing the application:

```
E Fri Sep 28 19:26:53 GMT+300 2018 AssertionError: Assertion failed: DirectoryDao.isFilterSupported: Filtering on 'PrimaryOrganizationDepartment' is not supported.

E Fri Sep 28 19:26:53 GMT+300 2018 Executing query for datasource DepartmentMembers: (Error) : Assertion failed: DirectoryDao.isFilterSupported: Filtering on 'PrimaryOrganizationDepartment' is not supported.

E Fri Sep 28 19:26:53 GMT+300 2018 Executing query for datasource DepartmentMembers failed.
```

Here is the code I have:

```
function getUserDeptWorkers()
{
  var result = [];
  var dept;
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var newQuery = app.models.Person.newQuery();
  newQuery.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = email;
  var userRecords = newQuery.run();
  if (userRecords.length === 0) {
    // got no information for this user
      return [];
  } else {
    var user = userRecords[0];
    dept = user.PrimaryOrganizationDepartment;
  }

  var deptQuery = app.models.Person.newQuery();
  deptQuery.filters.PrimaryOrganizationDepartment._equals = dept;
  var coWorkers = deptQuery.run();
  if (coWorkers.length === 0)
  {
    return [];
  }


  result.push(coWorkers);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell the reason why you are having that error as your question is missing information to help me assit you with debugging; Nevertheless, I do understand what you are trying to achieve and here are the steps I've taken:
1. Create a directory model and name it "persons" or whatever you want.
[image]
2. Create a datasource inside that model and name it "userDeptWorkers" or whatever you like.
[image]
3. Add this code to the query builder section of the datasource:
[image]

```
var results = [];
var allUsers = query.run();
var user;
for(var i=0; i<allUsers.length; i++){
  if(allUsers[i].PrimaryEmail === Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()){
    user = allUsers[i];
    break;
  }
}

for(var k=0; k<allUsers.length; k++){
  if(allUsers[k].PrimaryOrganizationDepartment === user.PrimaryOrganizationDepartment){
    results.push(allUsers[k]);
  }
}

return results;
```

4. In a test page, drop a table with the datasource being the "userDeptWorkers" or whatever you named it and preview the app. You should get what you need.

In the future, chances are that you might run into a more complicated issue, if that is the case, I recommend to be more specific with your question, i.e. include screenshots of what you are doing, explain more in detail where the datasources are located( if they are part of the same model or not), and if running a server script, how are you calling it.

I hope this helps you for now!